# Backbone relation model and collection.length

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

Let's suppose I have the following model (model1) and collection (collection1)

```
model1.attributes = {
   name: 'bar'
};

collection1.models = [{}, {}, {}];
```

It will be possible by using backbone relation to make  the `model1` to know about the length of `collection1`?

```
model1.attributes = {
   name: 'bar',
   collection1Length = 3 // collection1.models.length
}
```

Thanks

Comment: @jakee I would like to make one-to-one relation between `model1.attributes` and `collection1.models.length` in order to get the `collection1.models.length` from `model1`.

Comment: does collection1 contain model1's

Comment: No, it does not, but collection1 is related to model1 by `model1.id = collection1.models.creator_id`

Comment: am I understanding you in that, in a general sense, you want the model to know the length of the collection to which it belongs?

Comment: wait, just re-read your previous comment. So, `model1` is creating the models for another collection?

Comment: @jackwanders and @jakee  `model1` and `collection1` are separated but the `collection1.fetch` depends on `model1.id`

Comment: @LorraineBernard do you just want model1 to know the length of collection1, or do you want model1 to **set** the length of collection1?

Comment: @jackwanders I just want model1 to know about the length of collection1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, it might be best to simply create a reference to the collection itself within the model:

```
ModelName = Backbone.Model.extend({
    ...
    linked_collection: null // don't call this 'collection', as model.collection already exists
    ...
}

var model1 = new ModelName();
model1.set('linked_collection',collection1);
```

Now you can do this at any time to get the linked collection's length.

```
model1.get('linked_collection').length
```

Comment: +1 Ok what you say works, but what about a cleaner solution by using `Backbone.Relation`?

Comment: @LorraineBernard I assume you're referring to the `backbone-relational` plugin. I don't have any experience with that, so I can't help with a solution specific to that plugin